# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch in for loop with solve function outputting 2x1 from 1x1 inputs

Tags: arrays, matlab, dimension

In MATLAB, I am trying to run an iterating solve function that solves a quadratic equation. Each iteration enters the loop as a 1x1 matrix from a 1x6 array, but the for loop wants to shoehorn the 2x1 answer into the 1x1 allocated space.

I've researched cells and structures but to no avail could I get them to work. The equation works if take the for loop off and just solve for each function individually, but the goal is to scale this for loop up to churn through a lot more than just a 1x6 array. Here is my code.

```
    Es=200E3;        %MPa
    Ys=448;          %MPa
    D=168.3;         %mm
    wall=7.11;       %mm
    Pdesign=27.25;
    Ec=23800;
    strainc=.003;
    ts=7.11-7.11*.8;

    Plive=[5.45 8.18 10.90 13.63 16.35 19.08];
    syms trepair;

    for ii=1:1:length(Plive)

        test(ii)=solve(strainc==(Pdesign*D)/(2*Ec*trepair)-Ys*ts/(Ec*trepair)-Plive(ii)*D/(2*(Ec*trepair+Es*ts))); 

    end
```

Thanks in advance for y'alls input.

Comment: Do you have to solve symbolically?  Why not rewrite the equation to solve for trepair directly?

Comment: Matt, I don't follow how not using symbols changes the output array from a 2x1. Could you explain a little more? Thank you.

Comment: The nature of your equation requires 2 solutions for trepair because it is quadratic with respect to trepair, if I did the math right.  Solving for trepair would show you that and would help write a loop (or function) to solve it using the quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are 2x1 arrays, so you need to assign them to 2x1 arrays, not 1x1 arrays. Replace `test(ii)` with `test(2*ii-1:(2*ii))`.

Alternatively, solve with `PLive` as a symbolic variable, and then use `matlabFunction` to get solutions for whatever values you'd like:

```
Plive=[5.45 8.18 10.90 13.63 16.35 19.08];
syms trepair Pl
T=matlabFunction(solve(strainc==(Pdesign*D)/(2*Ec*trepair)-Ys*ts/(Ec*trepair)-Pl*D/(2*(Ec*trepair+Es*ts)),trepair));    
T(Plive)
```